# Plugin (floatThead.js) doesn't work anymore after resolving major error

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

My IDE changed the opening head-tag to an opening script-tag. I have imported the plugin (floatThead) via a cdn and it worked fine. After I've discovered the error and resolved it, the plugin no longer works. I haven't changed anything else and am at my wits end.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>


<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Images -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{{ asset('img/favicon.png') }}}">

{{--JS--}}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

{{--floatThead--}}
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/floatthead/2.1.3/jquery.floatThead.js"></script>

{{--Script for toggling between showing and hiding competences--}}
<script>
    // expand competences
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#competenceToggler').click(function () {
            $('#competencesForm').slideToggle()
        })
    })
</script>

</head>
```

Comment: Maybe these "comments" are breaking your page: `{{--JS--}}`, `{{--floatThead--}}`, etc. Try surrounding them with `<!--`  and `-->` instead.

Comment: @DelenaMalan These are normal Laravel comments. They get completely ignored. Just to make sure I changed them to HTML comments and I got the same output.